# setInterval calls the function just once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to execute the function below every 500ms

```
  function moveActualCam(where) {
    console.log("Called");
    seq_json = {
      direzione: where,
    };
    async function postData() {
      const url = "fetchcammove";

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(seq_json),
      });
      return await response.json();
    }
    postData().then((data) => {
      console.log("OK");
    });
  }
```

I'm calling the function from the HTML with

```
  <button
    onmousedown="moveCam('LEFT');"
    onmouseup="stopMoveCam();"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
  >
```

and my JS is

```
<script>
  const csrftoken = document.querySelector("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").value;
  function moveActualCam(where) {
    console.log("Called");
    seq_json = {
      direzione: where,
    };
    async function postData() {
      const url = "fetchcammove";

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(seq_json),
      });
      return await response.json();
    }
    postData().then((data) => {
      console.log("OK");
    });
  }

  function moveCam(where) {
    intervalCam = setInterval(moveActualCam(where), 500);
  }

  function stopMoveCam() {
    clearInterval(intervalCam);
  }
</script>
```

But for some reason the `setInterval` executes the function just once

Comment: `setInterval(moveActualCam(where), 500);` -------> `setInterval(() => moveActualCam(where), 500);`

Comment: the setInterval receives a callback to a function so it should be something like `setInterval(() => { moveActualCam(where) }, 500);`

Comment: or `setInterval(moveActualCam, 500, where);`

Comment: what's the point of the -1